# Is it safe to install Adblock plus on firefox?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

Is it safe to install Adblock plus on firefox?

Comment: You can follow this blog [-Adblock Plus and (a little) more-](http://adblockplus.org/category/security/) to read about security-related issues.

Comment: What would be a scenario where it would be _unsafe_ to install Adblock plus?

Comment: If you worked for an online advertising firm and it was the demo workstation for use during prospective client visits? *(implausible? certainly. But you asked! ha)*

Comment: But then you may want to prove that you can bypass the ABP add-on :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the add-on is 100% safe.

Even if it was malicious, Firefox's add-ons are sandboxed so they have no interaction with your operating system.

Adblock Plus has a very large userbase (I use it too) so that is another factor you have to look at.

Unless you are installing it on a work computer and there is a policy put in place saying you aren't allowed, it's all good. The only issue you may run across is that some websites require you to see their ads in order to see their content or for them to function correctly.

Comment: Adblock Plus is the first extension I install on Firefox.  When I install Fx for others, sometimes it's the only extension I install.

Comment: Same here. I will install the latest version of Flash and JavaRE, that's it.

Comment: ABP and Download Statusbar here.  +1 for the mention that it will sometimes break sites, particularly games or video streaming sites which play an ad in the player for the thing you actually want to let through.  Fortunately, disabling ABP on a per page or per site basis is easy.